# How to run multiple versions of Symfony PHP Framework

Tags: php, symfony1

I have several web projects built with Symfony v1.0, but I am excited by the new features in Symfony version 1.4 (Improved security, native email support and improved performance).

How can I continue to develop my 1.0 projects but also create a testing environment for version 1.4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Guide to Installing Multiple versions of Symfony

Thankyou to Guillaume Flandre for pointing it out, there is a [fantastic article](http://symfonynerds.com/blog/?p=123) written by eHabib on [SymfonyNerds.com](http://symfonynerds.com/) - http://symfonynerds.com/blog/?p=123

Here is the **basic outline**, read the whole article [here](http://symfonynerds.com/blog/?p=123).

**Step 1** - Un-install Symfony via PEAR

**Step 2** - Setup a structure for Symfony: Install symfony in **/usr/share/php/symfony**

**Step 3** - Checkout each Symfony version you need

Use SVN checkout to grab each Symfony version. Put these in a different folder under the base Symfony directory.

**Step 4** - Create symbolic links for each version

Create and test symlinks for each version of Symfony. Lets place these in the standard bin directory

**Step 5** - Creating a new project

Use the relevant Symfony command. For example, to create a Symfony 1.0 project:

- sudo symfony10 init-project test1
- sudo symfony11 generate:project test11
- sudo symfony12 generate:project test12

**Step 6** - Check in the project Config to ensure its picked up the right version.

Answer (score 5):

This link should be useful: http://symfonynerds.com/blog/?p=123

It points to an article named: **Your complete guide to running multiple Symfony versions on the same environment**

It's fairly easy to do.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, I have summarised the article in a new answer

Answer (score 1):

As also said in the article, I define it in lib/vendor as svn:externals: symfony http://svn.symfony-project.com/branches/1.2

So there's no symfony to be installed on the server at all and you can use as many versions without influence on other apps.